# order confirmation email not send in magento 2.4.5-p1

Tags: magento2.4.5

Magento ver. 2.4.5-p1 Orders do not generate an email.

All other actions do generate an email like shipping, processing, etc..

Probably a backend issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in Magento feature to test email sending. Go to Stores > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail Sending Settings. Here, you can enter your email address and send a test email. Check if you receive the test email.

Comment: "Here, you can enter your email address and send a test email.". No such field.

Comment: Sorry, u can't add email but... please check setup https://prnt.sc/4MyjYDwBvK6T as mention in link.

Comment: OK, it works , but with Mageplazza SMTP extension..

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do it is to open a (test-)order with your preferred mail address, add a comment and check "Notify Customer by Mail":
[image: Magento backend screenshot]

As you can see you can also use an order with status "complete". I admit that this is quite a hacky solution, would prefer to have something to test mail settings out-of-the-box.